Twilio edge location for websocket connection
I know there is a way to configure edge location for twilio REST API, but I need it for websocket connection (twilio media-stream) to boost performance. Websocket connection to my server created by twilio client.
Is there a way to somehow configure twilio account, or use some parameters/verbs in twiML to use specific edge location for websocket connection?


Is there a way to somehow configure twilio account, or use some parameters/verbs in twiML to use specific edge location for websocket connection?

No, the Media Stream feature of Twilio’s Programmable Voice does not support Edge Locations.
As of this writing, the only features listed within Programmable Voice that do support Edge Locations are the REST API, Sending SIP & Receiving SIP.
